# iOS swift deeplink https:// or http:// schema

Tags: swift, xcode

in my app I use myappname:// schema for deep link. 
and my share link in whatsapp be like:

myappname://pathtowebsite.com

is there possible to use https:// or http:// as schema? so my share link is like to:
https://pathtowebsite.com

Comment: No you can not use this as its predefined schema.

Comment: I think what are you are looking at is something called as deferred deep linking, there are some 3rd party solutions available for a price. It works just like how you want, share link with `https`, if an app is installed it gets redirected else its redirected to app store.

Comment: @GoodSp33d can you explain more? or show me best 3rd party solution?

Comment: I think the problem with myappname:// schema is not clickable in WhatsApp , did you find work around?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation about universal links https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html?utm_source=revxblog